# How to resolve JEST error duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_pkey"

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, jestjs

I'm writing tests with JEST and seems my clear DB part doesn't work.
I'm always getting the following error:

```
study-service_1  | server-0   | info: Connection opened
postgres_1       | 2020-12-18 14:35:51.993 UTC [98] ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "sites_pkey"
postgres_1       | 2020-12-18 14:35:51.993 UTC [98] DETAIL:  Key (id)=(3) already exists.
postgres_1       | 2020-12-18 14:35:51.993 UTC [98] STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO sites (id, name, address, city, country_code, study_id, site_id, status, timezone, "default") VALUES(3, 'site 3','address', 'city', 'dk', 'DEFAULT1', 'site 3', 'ACTIVE', 'Europe/Rome', false)
study-service_1  |   console.error node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine/Env.js:157
study-service_1  |     Unhandled error
study-service_1  |
study-service_1  |   console.error node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine/Env.js:158
study-service_1  |     error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "sites_pkey"
study-service_1  |         at Connection.Object.<anonymous>.Connection.parseE (/test/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:567:11)
study-service_1  |         at Connection.Object.<anonymous>.Connection.parseMessage (/test/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:391:17)
study-service_1  |         at Socket.<anonymous> (/test/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:129:22)
study-service_1  |         at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
study-service_1  |         at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
study-service_1  |         at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
study-service_1  |         at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
study-service_1  |         at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
```

I cannot understand the issue where is it and I did this data setup in my test

```
const sitesData = [
  {
    id: 11,
    name: "site 1",
    address: "address",
    city: "city",
    country_code: "es",
    study_id: "DEFAULT1",
    site_id: "site 1",
    status: "ACTIVE",
    timezone: "Europe/Rome",
    default: true,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "site 2",
    address: "address",
    city: "city",
    country_code: "es",
    study_id: "DEFAULT1",
    site_id: "site 2",
    status: "INACTIVE",
    timezone: "United States/New York",
    default: false,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "site 3",
    address: "address",
    city: "city",
    country_code: "dk",
    study_id: "DEFAULT1",
    site_id: "site 3",
    status: "ACTIVE",
    timezone: "Europe/Rome",
    default: false,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "site 4",
    address: "address",
    city: "city",
    country_code: "dk",
    study_id: "DEFAULT1",
    site_id: "site 4",
    status: "INACTIVE",
    timezone: "Europe/Rome",
    default: false,
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "site 5",
    address: "address",
    city: "city",
    country_code: "pl",
    study_id: "DEFAULT1",
    site_id: "site 5",
    status: "INACTIVE",
    timezone: "Europe/Rome",
    default: false,
  },
];

const sitesData2 = [
  {
    id: 6,
    name: "site 6",
    address: "address",
    city: "city",
    country_code: "es",
    study_id: "DEFAULT2",
    site_id: "site 6",
    status: "INACTIVE",
    timezone: "Europe/Rome",
    default: false,
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: "site 7",
    address: "address",
    city: "city",
    country_code: "it",
    study_id: "DEFAULT2",
    site_id: "site 7",
    status: "INACTIVE",
    timezone: "United States/New York",
    default: true,
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    name: "site 8",
    address: "address",
    city: "city",
    country_code: "dk",
    study_id: "DEFAULT2",
    site_id: "site 8",
    status: "INACTIVE",
    timezone: "Europe/Rome",
    default: false,
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    name: "site 9",
    address: "address",
    city: "city",
    country_code: "dk",
    study_id: "DEFAULT2",
    site_id: "site 9",
    status: "INACTIVE",
    timezone: "Europe/Rome",
    default: false,
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    name: "site 10",
    address: "address",
    city: "city",
    country_code: "pl",
    study_id: "DEFAULT2",
    site_id: "site 10",
    status: "INACTIVE",
    timezone: "Europe/Rome",
    default: false,
  },
]

const serviceWithDAO = (daoMocks) => {
  return SiteService({
    withDAO: block => (
      block(daoMocks)
    ),
  });
}

const Data = {
  data: [],
  get value() {
    return this.data;
  },
  set value(v) {
    this.data = v;
  },
  get mock() {
    return {
      select: jest.fn(({ studyId }) => {
        return Promise.resolve(this.data.filter((i) => i.study_id === studyId));
      }),
    };
  },
};


async function clearDatabase() {
  await Promise.all([
    dbClient.query("DELETE FROM studies WHERE id='DEFAULT1'"),
    ...sitesData.map((site) =>
      dbClient.query(`DELETE FROM sites WHERE site_id='${site.id}'`)
    ),
  ],
  [
    dbClient.query("DELETE FROM studies WHERE id='DEFAULT2'"),
    ...sitesData2.map((site) =>
      dbClient.query(`DELETE FROM sites WHERE site_id='${site.id}'`)
    ),
  ]);
  dbClient.disconnect();
}

async function initializeDatabase() {
  await dbClient.connect();
  await Promise.all([
    dbClient.query("DELETE FROM studies WHERE id='DEFAULT1'"),
    ...sitesData.map((site) =>
      dbClient.query(`DELETE FROM sites WHERE site_id='${site.id}'`)
    ),
  ],[
    dbClient.query("DELETE FROM studies WHERE id='DEFAULT2'"),
    ...sitesData2.map((site) =>
      dbClient.query(`DELETE FROM sites WHERE site_id='${site.id}'`)
    ),
  ]);

  await Promise.all(
    [
      dbClient.query("INSERT INTO studies (id, internal_study_name, start_date) values ('DEFAULT1', 'Test DEFAULT SITE', '2030-10-10T08:00:00.000Z')")
    ],
    [
      dbClient.query("INSERT INTO studies (id, internal_study_name, start_date) values ('DEFAULT2', 'Test DEFAULT SITE 2', '2030-10-10T08:00:00.000Z')")
    ]
  );

  await Promise.all(
    [
      sitesData.map(site => dbClient.query(
       `INSERT INTO sites (id, name, address, city, country_code, study_id, site_id, status, timezone, "default") VALUES(${site.id}, '${site.name}','${site.address}', '${site.city}', '${site.country_code}', '${site.study_id}', '${site.site_id}', '${site.status}', '${site.timezone}', ${site.default})`)),
    ],
    [
      sitesData2.map(site => dbClient.query(
        `INSERT INTO sites (id, name, address, city, country_code, study_id, site_id, status, timezone, "default") VALUES(${site.id}, '${site.name}','${site.address}', '${site.city}', '${site.country_code}', '${site.study_id}', '${site.site_id}', '${site.status}', '${site.timezone}', ${site.default})`)),

    ]);
  const { rows: input } = await dbClient.query(`SELECT name, address, study_id, "default", country_code, site_id, status FROM sites`);
  Data.value = input;
}

beforeAll(() => {
  return initializeDatabase();
});

afterAll(() => {
  return clearDatabase();
});
```

This data is used as base setup for the tests I'm running

```
describe('Default Site', async () => {
  test('Undefined no sites of a study', async () => {
    const service = serviceWithDAO({ sites: Data.mock});
    console.log(Data.value);
    const defaultSite = await service.getDefaultSite({ studyId: 'DEF001', locale: 'us_ES'});
    console.log('DEFAULT SITE',defaultSite);
    expect(defaultSite).toBeUndefined();
  });

  test('C1 - is default, same country, active', async () => {
    const service = serviceWithDAO({ sites: Data.mock});
    const defaultSite = await service.getDefaultSite({ studyId: 'DEFAULT1', locale: 'us_ES'});
    console.log('C1', defaultSite);
    expect(defaultSite.default).toBeTruthy();
    expect(defaultSite.country_code).toEqual('es');
    expect(defaultSite.status).toEqual('ACTIVE');
    expect(defaultSite.site_id).toEqual('site 1');
  });

  test('C2 - is default, same country, inactive', async () => {
    const service = serviceWithDAO({ sites: Data.mock});
    const defaultSite = await service.getDefaultSite({ studyId: 'DEFAULT2', locale: 'us_IT'});
    console.log('C2', defaultSite);
    expect(defaultSite.default).toBeTruthy();
    expect(defaultSite.country_code).toEqual('it');
    expect(defaultSite.status).toEqual('INACTIVE');
    expect(defaultSite.site_id).toEqual('site 7');
  });
```

I tried to delete and clear DB in my promises but seems something not working.

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing both the clear and initialise in the `beforeAll` hook, this might help if the problem is caused by a previous test run failing:

```
beforeAll(async () => {
  await clearDatabase();
  await initializeDatabase();
});

afterAll(() => {
  await clearDatabase();
});
```

Alternatively, a good way to handle databases within tests is to create a clean database for each test run. The [@databases/pg-test](https://www.atdatabases.org/docs/pg-test) library can help you set this up for Jest. It will be a completely clean database, so you will need to create the tables before you can actually interact with them in your tests.

Comment: Unfortunate this does not solved my issue

Comment: In that case you are probably just inserting data that violates the constraint within the test, or failing to clear all the data you need to when calling clearDatabase. I suggest you look at all the queries that insert into sites and check that they aren't specifying the same id multiple times.